# Why is this weighted average measure correct?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I was ding some DAX exercises and came across this measure:

```
Average Return on Investment =
DIVIDE (
SUMX (
fact_RoI;
fact_RoI[Return on Investment] * [SumInvestment]
);
SUMX ( fact_RoI;[SumInvestment] )
)
```

This measure works, but can someone explain to me why they are using a SUMX in the bottom part as well? I tried just using the SumInvestments measure instead and got very wrong result, but I do not understand why.

edit: adding this as requested (sorry, didn't think it was relevant)

```
SumInvestment =
CALCULATE (
   SUM ( fact_Investments[Investment] );
CROSSFILTER (
  fact_RoI[Product];
  dim_Product[Product];
  Both))
```

Comment: what's the formula for [SumInvestment] measure?

Comment: SumInvestment =
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( fact_Investments[Investment] );
CROSSFILTER (
   fact_RoI[Product];
   dim_Product[Product];
   Both))

Comment: The issue is the [SumInvestment] measure; however, it's necessary to see the data model/relationships diagram to explain further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SUMX ( fact_RoI;[SumInvestment] ) iterates over the fact_RoI table, however the Measure SumInvestment sums a column from another table (fact_Investments). Thus if you want to obtain a calculation based on the RoI you would need to iterate over it as in the example.
Otherwise the SUM of fact_Investment probably just produces a meaningless result, like: sum all investments regardless of their connection to RoI.